# How to convert selenium webelelements to list of strings in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, selenium, web-scraping

I have gathered obligatory data from the scopus website. my outputs have been saved in a list named "document". when I use type method for each element of this list, the python returns me this class:

```
"<class'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement'>"
```

In continius in order to solve this issue, I have used text method such this:
`document=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')`

```
for i in document:  
    print i.text
```

So, I could see the result in text format. But, when I call each element of the list independently, white space is printed in this code:

```
x=[]
for i in document:
     x.append(i.text)
```

`print (x[2])` will return white space.
What should I do?

Comment: What is the current and desired output? Can you share HTML code sample for the same?

Comment: Why don't you try `x.append(i.text.strip())`. You can have elements which have no text or some spaces in it.

Comment: As a result, a part of my output is as below:
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'An efficient genetic algorithm for large-scale planning of dense and robust industrial wireless networks', u'Gong, X., Plets, D., Tanghe, E...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have used the following line of code :

```
document=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
```

and see the output on Console as :

```
"<class'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement'>"
```

This is the expected behavior as **`Selenium`** prints the reference of the **`Nodes`** matching your search criteria.

As per your `Code Attempt` to print the text leaving out the  `white spaces` you can use the following code block :

```
x=[]
document = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
for i in document :
    if (i.get_attribute("innerHTML") != "null") :
    x.append(i.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
print(x[2])
```

Comment: Still, the problem remains. Also, another issue will happen within this code.

Comment: What is your issue now? Have you tried the code? It's unclear from your Question why you are trying to scrape `<td>` which will contain a lot other child tags and `text`

Answer (score 1):

My code was correct. But, the selected elements for displaying were space. By select another element, the result was shown.