# Why unicode elements of lists would be hide?

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, selenium, python-unicode

If I want to display Unicode elements as string correctly, why should I do, in the English language?

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Could you convert my_list from Unicode to string?
my_list=[[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'An efficient genetic algorithm for large-scale planning of dense and robust industrial wireless networks', u'Gong, X., Plets, D., Tanghe, E., (...), Martens, L., Joseph, W.']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert selenium webelelements to list of strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959991/convert-selenium-webelelements-to-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: @hamedbaziyad Can you show your code trials? How is it related to `Selenium`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can encode each item one by one into utf-8 if thats what you wanted.

```
list = [u"hi",u"Whatever",u"Hello"]
map(lambda item: item.encode("utf-8"), list)
```

Outputs

```
['hi', 'Whatever', 'Hello']
```

See the following for more details on [the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10973766/2750819). You can also just use python3 if thats an option.